# QML - how can i scale an item from javascript?

Tags: javascript, qml, qtquick2

After creating an object from javascript using:

```
function createNextItem(item, where) {
    component = Qt.createComponent(val);
    sprite = component.createObject(where, {
                                    "id": "currentitem",
                                    "anchors.left": nextlabel.right,
                                    "anchors.leftMargin": units.gu(4),
                                    "anchors.verticalCenter": nextlabel.verticalCenter
                                });

    if (sprite === null) {
        // Error Handling
        console.log("Error creating object");
    }
}
```

if i try to add `"transform": Scale { xScale: 0.5 ; yScale: 0.5}` i get an `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` but if i do something like this `"transform": "Scale { xScale: 0.5 ; yScale: 0.5}"`, it does not work... any help?

Answer (score 2):

Never mind... i got it by making a container parent item, scaling it and then creating the new object in it, something like this:

```
Item {
    id: currentitem
    transform: Scale { xScale: 0.5; yScale: 0.5}
    Component.onCompleted: { Jsfile.createItemObjects(ChkItem.getCurrentItem(), currentitem)
        }
    }
```